# Combining an if statement with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, wordpress-theming

The current code, searches for the first `image` and first `iframe`. However, I want it to only show the first it found, not the first of both. If the `iframe` was found first, show that. If the `image`, show that.

```
function first_item() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_item = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();

  if ( preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches)) {
      $first_item = $matches [1] [0];
 echo "<img src=" . $first_item . ">";

}  if (preg_match_all('/<iframe.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches)) { 

      $first_item = $matches [1] [0];

  echo "<iframe src=" . "'" . $first_item  . "'" . "/"  .">" . "</iframe>";

 } }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use preg_match_all, you only need preg_match for a single match:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
## begining of the tag ##
<i (mg|frame) \b  # capture group 1: to know which tag name it is

## all possible content before the src attribute ##
(?>
    [^s>]++         # all that is not a "s" or a ">" (to fail at the tag end) 
  |
    \B s++          # "s" without a word boundary can't be the "s" from "src" 
  |
    s (?!rc \s*+ =) # "s" not followed by "rc="
)++                 # repeat the group one or more times
                    # (there is at least a space)

## from the attribute name until the begining of the attribute value ##
src \s*+ = \s*+ ["']?+  # spaces and quote are optional

## attribute value ##
( [^\s"'>]++ ) # capture group 2: url
               # the value can't contain spaces, quotes, or >, since it is
               # an URL
~ix
LOD;

if (preg_match($pattern, $post->post_content, $match)) {
    $first_item = $match[2];
    if ($match[1]=='mg') 
        echo '<img src="' . $first_item . '"/>';
    else
        echo '<iframe src="' . $first_item . '"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: How would I then append the '</iframe'> or </>?

Comment: Perfect! I added a closing bracket to the if statement, though

Comment: @mtanti: note that you are free to use more spaces and comments. The goal of the pattern is to avoid lazy quantifiers (that are slow) and backtracking. You can see too that the pattern allows src attribute without quotes.

Comment: @mtanti: with one pattern instead of two you parse the string only once.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes but there's a trade off between increasing performance and making debugging easier.

Comment: @mtanti: Ok, I will write a more easy readable version of the same pattern (however there is no need to debug it:))

Answer (score 0):

Since both use the `src` attribute, you can take a shortcut:

```
'/<(img|iframe).+src=...............................>/i'
```

However, be aware that the pony is watching...

Comment: just use [^>]* instead of lots of dots
    '/<(img|iframe).+src=[^>]*>/i'

Comment: The dots are there because I couldn't be bothered to type out the rest of the regex, or go copy-paste it. I was trying to emphasize the alternation at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Get both matches, find which occurs first, show that.

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $img_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
preg_match('/<iframe.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $iframe_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if ($img_matches[0][1] < $iframe_matches[0][1]) {
  echo "image first";
}
else {
  echo "iframe first";
}
```

This assumes that both of the image and the iframe are in the content. Otherwise check if the matches found anything first.

Answer (score 0):

**I create an example, i hope this will be useful:**

```
function catch_that_image() {
      global $post, $posts;
      $first_img = '';
      $iframe = '';
      $link = get_permalink($postID);

      ob_start();
      ob_end_clean();

      $first_img_output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $first_img_matches);
      $first_img = $first_img_matches[1][0];

      $iframe_output = preg_match_all('/<iframe.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*><\/iframe>/i', $post->post_content, $iframe_matches);
      $iframe = $iframe_matches[1][0];

      if ( $first_img < $iframe ) {
        echo('<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;"><iframe src="' . $iframe . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
      } else {
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="block-thumb">';
        echo('<img src="'.$first_img.'">');
        echo '</a>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you would add comments or text between code comments explaining what have you done.